# Open Yaml file outside the directory

Tags: ruby, cucumber, yaml

I wantto have a common Yml file with the configurations built inside it across all the directories inside a master folder.

I have a folder called `ROMauto` and a directory within that called `Mobile`

The `test_data.yml` is stored outside the `Mobile` directory but within the `ROMauto`.

I want to access this `test_data.yml` from the `Mobile` folder. I can do the same being inside the `ROMauto` as it is sourcing from the same directory.

How do I read the `YAML` outside its directory?

I tried it with

```
@datasource = YAML.load_file("test_data.yml")

YAML::load(File.open('ROMauto/test_data.yml)'))

fn = File.dirname(File.expand_path(FILE)) + '../../test_data.yml'
YAML::load(File.open(fn))

YAML::load_file(File.join(File.dirname(File.expand_path(__FILE__)), 'test_data.yml'))
```

from the `Mobile` folder and it still throws me this error called:

```
No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - test_data.yml (Errno::ENOENT)
```

Is there a way to call and read the YAML from outside the directory?

Comment: Relative paths work pretty fine: `'../../ROMauto/test_data.yml'`. Also, you have a typo: the closing parenthesis in your second line inside quotes.

Comment: Tried with `fn = YAML::load_file ('../../ROMauto/test_data.yml')` and `YAML::load(File.open('../../ROMauto/test_data.yml'))` it still throws me no file error :( .

Comment: It heavily depends on where this is executed from and how do you run the application/file in the first place. `puts __dir__` to examine where you are and/or `"#{__dir__}/../ROMauto/test_data.yml"` (note doubñe quotes needed for string interpolation.)

Comment: This is executed from `Mobile` directory which is within the `ROMauto` where the `test_data.yml` is placed.

I am placing this inside an `rb` file and I am assigning this to a variable and printing it out for now as I run the `.rb` file

Comment: @mudasobwa So I tried with `File.dirname("#{__dir__}/../ROMAuto/test_data.yml") and executed that .rb file within the `Mobile` directory and I still get, file not found. Weird!

I am trying to print the `_dir_` to again get `file not found?`

Comment: I am currently in `/Users/admin/Documents/Automation/ROMauto/Mobile/features/support`

The `test_data.yml` is in `/Users/admin/Documents/Automation/ROMauto`

Comment: Then count how many times you should go up _better_ :) It’s `'../../../../ROMAuto/test_data.yml'`.

Comment: My Initial manual attempt was that, but that didnt work :(. Tried with 5, 4, 3, 2 , 1 times of going up...! Noob me!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171447/discussion-between-mrityunjeyan-s-and-mudasobwa).

Comment: @mudasobwa Jesus! It was all the problem with the IDE not saving the changes that I was doing. Holy Crap! After quitting and launching it works. I spent like 3 hours on this Damn file thing without knowing it

Answer (score 1):

```
file = File.expand_path("../../test_data.yml", __FILE__)
YAML.load_file(file)
```

should work for you. First it will resolve the parent of current file, that is 'Mobile/', then go to the parent, and appends test_data.yml.